# Есть ли ли шансы у русского языка на свободу выбора: "ья" или "ия"?

Tags: окончания, поэзия, рифма

> Говори, не знай смятенья. 
>   Русский язык – лучшее средство выраженья!

Собственно, допускается ли слова "смятенья" и "выраженья" хотя бы в данном контексте (рифмы)? Или только "смятение" и "выражение".

Comment: Дополняю свой опрос: правильно ли я понял, что в обычном предложении, будь-то как :"Картина - это не только рисунок, но и средство выраженья". 
Тоже допускается писать "выраженья", а не выражение"?

Comment: Нет, Денис. Если Вы не маститый писатель, которому обожающая публика простит любую вольность, Вы имеете право только на ***-ия*** в данном прозаическом контексте.

Comment: А если я не маститый писатель, а всего лишь внимательно читающий ваш ответ?
"Более того, будет ошибкой писать в нейтральном тексте -ия, если слово относится к сниженной или просторечной лексике" – это было написано к чему?

Comment: Это было написано к правилам русского языка.

Comment: И еще раз: Если я НЕ маститый писатель, могу я написать "Картина - это не только рисунок, но и средство выраженья" и будет ли это грамматической ошибку?
Да или нет?

Comment: В прозаическом тексте ДА, это будет СТИЛИСТИЧЕСКОЙ (а шире - ГРАММАТИЧЕСКОЙ) ошибкой.

Comment: Вот теперь СПАСИБО ВАМ ГАЛИНА! Я хочу с вами дружить. Если не сложно, сообщите свою почту. Я вышлю вам письма с чувствами, ибо на этом форуме чувства, как и люди, могут потеряться (что у меня уже было неоднократно).

Comment: Денис, место общения - здесь; я работаю, не успеваю. Знак благодарности за ответ - клик по нижней галочке слева от ответа.

Answer (score 3):

В стихах (лозунгах, слоганах, девизах, речовках, поговорках, пословицах, идиомах, присловьях) - вполне допускается **-ья**.

**[Муза](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B0_(%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9))**

> Не ослеплён я Музою моею:
>
> Красавицей её не назовут
>
> И юноши, узрев её, за нею
>
> Влюблённою толпой не побегут.
>
> Приманивать изысканным убором,
>
> Игрою глаз, блестящим разговором,
>
> Ни склонности у ней, ни дара нет;
>
> Но поражён бывает мельком свет
>
> Её лица необщим **выраженьем**,
>
> Её речей спокойной простотой;
>
> И он, скорей чем едким **осужденьем**,
>
> Её почтит небрежной похвалой.
>
> 1829

Более того, будет ошибкой писать в нейтральном тексте **-ия**, если слово относится к сниженной или просторечной лексике:

кваканье, тявканье, кряканье и т. д.

У русского языка не только шансы - ОН СВОБОДЕН!

Припомните ВМПС им. Тургенева! )))

---

В приведённом ниже скриншоте досадно отсутствие одной - сравнительной! - строки, последней:

> И на обломках самовластья
>
> Напишут наши имена!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следует также помнить, что в смысловом отношении различаются: варение, печение, соление (процесс, то же, что «варка», «выпечка», «засол» – варенье, печенье, соленье как результат процесса, продукт); воскресение (действие по глаголу воскресить) – воскресенье (день недели); жалование (пожалование, присуждение) — жалованье (денежное вознаграждение за работу)] и т. п.

---

Дополню ответ интересной находкой (я искала подходящий фразеологизм для примера):

**[«Не мытьём, так катаньем»](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/95035/20/Balyazin_04_Nachalo_Petrovskoii_epohi.html)**

> Вот еще одно крылатое выражение, пришедшее к нам из XVII столетия,
> которое и сегодня существует как поговорка: «Не мытьем, так катаньем».
> И чаще всего мы связываем ее со стиркой и глаженьем белья. Только при
> добавлении слов: «Я заставлю тебя сделать это не мытьем, так катаньем»
> – мы задумываемся лишь иногда, как «мытьем» или «катаньем» можно
> заставить человека сделать то, чего он не хочет?
>
> А теперь раскроем подлинный смысл этой старинной пословицы, возникшей
> в период Средневековья: «мыт» – пошлина за что-либо, которую взимали
> «мытари» – сборщики пошлин. Отсюда – глагол «мытарить» и выражение
> «терпеть, переносить всяческие мытарства». Что же касается слова
> «катанье», то оно происходит от слова «кат», что значит «палач,
> мучитель, заплечных дел мастер», и потому «катанье» – мучение, пытка.
> Таким образом, пословица «Не мытьем, так катаньем» означает: «не
> поборами, так мучениями».

Comment: Насколько помню, даётся даже индульгенция на -ньи в предложном падеже, вместо нормативного -нии и либерализованного -нье. Пушкин этим не всегда пользовался, но бывало ("сердце... в упоенье", но "Прозерпина в упоеньи").

Comment: Саша, я не слышала о такой индульгенции... Спросите "университетку" Людмилу, она всё-превсё знает! https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/247/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: Огромное преспасибо, Galina. 
Правильно ли я понял, что в обычном предложении, будь-то как "Картина - это не только рисунок, но и средство выраженья". Тоже допускается писать "выраженья", а не выражение"?

Comment: Денис, я вначале увидела коммент к вопросу и ответила на него. Если это Ваш текст, в приватных целях написанный, то лучше исправить. Если же кто-то (на то уполномоченный) отметил ***-ья*** как  ошибку - нарушение нейтрального стиля, он прав.

Comment: А я вначале увидел ваш ответ, поэтому и отвечайте на него там же :-)